# LibGDX Scene2d.ui Adaptive size with dip

Tags: java, android, libgdx

This is my code:

```
public class Menu implements Screen {

private MyGdxGame gameInstance;
public Stage stage;
public Table root;
public Label wellcomeLabel;
public TextButton startButton;

public Menu(MyGdxGame gameInstance) {
    this.gameInstance = gameInstance;
    stage = new Stage();
    root = new Table();
    root.setDebug(true);
    root.setFillParent(true);
    root.top();
    stage.addActor(root);

    wellcomeLabel = new Label("Wellcome!",gameInstance.labelStyle);
    startButton = new TextButton("Start",gameInstance.btnStyle);

    root.add(wellcomeLabel).pad(32);
    root.row();
    root.add(startButton).size(240,100);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float p1) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f,0.4f,0.4f,1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int p1, int p2) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

Tables can help us with adaptive position of actors, but how about the size? I have an idea: use dip(density-independent pixels).
But i heard this:

> Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen.

Does it mean that it is only based on the physical density of the screen, but isn't based on the screen size?
I wanna use it for size and padding of actors.

Comment: Yes, DIP is based purely on screen DPI. DIP is used on Android to maintain approximate equal sizing and spacing in real-world units. So if a button is 20mm wide on a tablet with high or low DPI, it will also be a 20mm wide on a tiny phone with high or low DPI. Is that what you're going for? Or do you want objects to take up the same percentage of the total screen size on any device?

Comment: Tenfour04, yes, i want to take up the same percentage of the total screen size on any device. I really don't understand: why Tables haven't adaptive size system? So, I know how to find percentage for size of actors, but what about padding? And text size? I use FreeType for font loading. Before I get the BitmapFont object, I set the size. How can fonts become adaptive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibGDX's UI system does not have any adaptive scaling. That means if you want to use ScreenViewport for pixel perfect assets, then when setting up the UI you must get the current screen dimensions and use them to calculate a scaling factor and multiply that by every dimension you use in setting up your UI.

I don't bother with any of that. Instead, I use the ExtendViewport to draw everything at a consistent scale on every screen:

- I make my UI assets at a decently large scale to look nice on any screen.
- My UI assets get their own TextureAtlas. I load this with trilinear filtering (MipMapLinearLinear, Linear). This is so the art still looks crisp when scaled down.
- On my BitmapFont I call `setUseIntegerPosition(false)` to allow non-integer positioning of the letters so the kerning doesn't go wonky when scaled up or down.
- I use ExtendViewport for my UI Stage instead of ScreenViewport. I select virtual dimensions based on what screen dimensions would work with my art assets if they were drawn at 1:1 pixel scale.
- No need to use any manual scaling. Padding and spacing and sizes can be declared in pixel units of my source art. The ExtendViewport takes care of the scaling for you.

Downsides to this process:

- It's wasteful with memory on screens with smaller dimensions because larger-than-necessary textures are loaded in memory.
- Text and UI elements are slightly less crisp than they would be if drawn pixel-perfect.
- It is heavier on the GPU to draw things with MipMapLinearLinear than with Nearest filtering.

The upside is you only have to manage a single UI TextureAtlas. You don't need to create it at multiple scales to make it look consistent across different screen sizes and densities. Units are easy to work with. And since you're using trilinear filtering, you can use scaling for animation effects and they'll look smooth. For instance, I use actions to make buttons do a quick scale-up animation when pressing them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is important for me